# What requireClientCertificate in httpstransport means?

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, https

According to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731818(v=vs.110).aspx) it means:

> A Boolean value that specifies if the server requires the client to
>   provide a client certificate as part of the HTTPS handshake. The
>   default is false.

and I'm being told that it means:

> Require client certificate false means, that the server accepts any
>   certificate from the client.  True means server accepts only trusted
>   certificates. A self signed certificate is also valid ...

I'm bit confused because of default value of this setting which is false, it doesn't make sense to me that you can have https without certificate or can you?

Answer (score 0):

You can have one way SSL. It means the server is providing a certificate to be clearly identifiable so the client can trust the endpoint he is sending requests to. However on his side, the server can accept any client and need to handle differently the authentication of the users.